# Unused Docker containers stuck in Removal in Progress state. Device or Resource Busy

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos7

I'm running Docker version 20.10.5 on a Centos 7 Box.  I stopped my project with `docker-compose down` and every container had the same message -

```
Error response from daemon: container <container ID>: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/<long number>/merged: device or resource busy
```

I've stopped the daemon, I've reinstalled Docker, I've tried `umount, lsof, kill`, and all the docker go-away commands including `system prune` but still they hang on.

(After re-installing Docker the status changes to `Dead`.  When I try to delete the zombie containers their status changes to `Removal In Progress`)

How can I get rid of these containers?

Comment: `docker rm <container-name>`?

Comment: Nope.  Gives device or resource busy

Comment: `docker ps` and get the running containers. `docker stop <container-name>` and then `docker rm <container-name>`

Comment: Is var/lib/docker/overlay2/ referencing a network device?

Comment: It seems to be - `df -h` brings me a lot of 
`overlay         1.8T   20G  1.7T   2% /home/virtfs/mysite/var/lib/docker/overlay2/069f1826c43fe01846bba92ffc34b4aa10fd2c3673494e779f135292b18d331a/merged`

and 
`shm              64M     0   64M   0% /home/virtfs/mysite/var/lib/docker/containers/22c0e31f41c192750a40b33db9d3c2e8a8382a5e0b8c83f85b72a5cd27093ed6/mounts/shm`
lines.

Comment: df -h shows each of the entries as members of both the overlay and shm filesystem, but any attempt to umount brings back a `not mounted` message.

Answer (score 6):

For people who have similar issues:
So I had similar issue where
`docker rm -f <docker name>` was hanging
The only thing that helped me was:

```
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu `22.04` with Docker engine `23.0.0` neither stopping/starting the Docker service nor a `docker system prune` removed the containers (still showing `Removal in progress`). The solution as [outlined here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10589#issuecomment-222468296) was to manually remove the volumes associated with the container(s):

- `sudo service docker stop`
- `sudo -i`
- `cd /var/lib/docker/containers`
- `rm -rf <container id>`
- `sudo service docker start`

Comment: You saved me! It worked on Ubuntu 22.04 and docker v23.0.1